# ol.Overlay scrolling map on IE and Firefox

Tags: javascript, html, css, overlay, openlayers-3

I am using OpenLayers 3.14 and its Overlay function to show a menu.

```
// JavaScript:
var popup = new ol.Overlay({
  element: document.getElementById('popup')
});
popup.setPosition(coordinate);
map.addOverlay(popup);

<!-- HTML -->
<div id="mapContainer">
   ..
   <!-- other map related stuff -->
   ..
   <div id="popup" class="ol-popup">
      <a href="#" id="popup-closer" class="ol-popup-closer"></a>
      <div id="popup-content"></div>
   </div>
</div>
```

In Firefox and Internet Explorer when I hover the menu by mouse and scroll from the wheel, the map zooms.

**In Chrome the list in popup scrolls, which is the correct behavior.**

**Why not in IE and FF?**

Comment: I've made some tests and it sounds like a bug, it doesn't happen with v3.12.

Comment: See https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/issues/4957

Comment: Thanks, @JonatasWalker! Your fiddles on github issue show exactly my issue. Please do answer shortly with answer button, I would accept it and try to live until the fix comes out.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is an already fixed bug. See [#4958](https://github.com/openlayers/ol3/pull/4958).

A patch (v3.14.2) is to be released very soon.